# How Can I Create An Immutable Database That Can Be Truncated?

Tags: database

I have a requirement from a bank where they need to store data in a tamper proof way but at the same time they need to purge it after 7 years.

The current process is they receive a letter and file it.
After 7 years they shred it.

The first part of the requirement can be achieved via a blockchain or an immutable database.
However, the second part is in conflict with that as they don't allow deletions.

How can I replicate this seemingly simple use case of receiving, storing and shredding a letter?

EDIT: Flag to close. It must not be worded well enough to generate this much discussion and non-software solutions.

Comment: Is there a regulatory requirement to prove data has not been altered via a checksum or blockchain?

Comment: What stops you from just deleting the older blocks on a blockchain, and only verifying the last N years of blocks? So long as the auditing process can verify the leading nodes haven't been tampered with, that should work fine.

Comment: @user1937198 that seems like it could be a solution but I didn't think it was an option in most blockchains.

Comment: @opticyclic I doubt it is, but I wouldn't be surprised if it wasn't hard to add. Assuming you don't need to write your own system due to different chain validation requirements. Mining isn't going to work as a tamper prevention process in a bank.

Comment: With the current process, whats the banks plan for if the archive storing the letters catches fire?

Comment: Another good use case for replacing the current system

Comment: Not an answer but: This sounds like a regulatory requirement. If you want to do it properly (and not the way the question imply - pick a tech solution that is the most exciting for you) you should figure out the exact reason for the requirement, learn about the underlying legal/regulatory requirements and finally find out what types of solutions satisfy the legal/regulatory requirement. Don't forget to include how the solution will be supported in 10-20 years - "No One Ever Got Fired for Buying IBM" joke has hidden truths including the company  is likely to be there for next years.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov If phrased carefully, Stack Exchange does support answers to questions which are [X-Y problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @PhilipKendall thanks for the reminder. I actually started writing it as an answer... but the "phrased carefully" part did not work out in my case to get full-fledged answer. I don't visit this site as often as SO to feel confident about boundary between answer and not really one so decided that comment is better choice.

Answer (score 5):

> After 7 years they shred it.

What stops them shredding it before 7 years? Answer: a process they have in place.

The answer here is a process, not a technical solution and absolutely definitely nothing to do with "cryptography".

Comment: +1 — furthermore, they are likely using the term "immutable" very loosely. Immutable in the sense that no updates are made to data and the only deletions allowed are when old data is purged. ... Unless there is a regulatory requirement to prove the data was not altered using something like a checksum.

Comment: That is exactly the case. You get a letter with financial information in it then you get another letter referencing the first. You can't just edit the row and say "the db says you actually owe us $1M and not $1k.

Comment: @opticyclic I just fake a copy of the first letter. You can't do this without a trusted third party.

Comment: When they delete it is a separate question. The data needs to be stored in a way that it can't be changed and there needs to be an audit of updates. An append only database seems to fit this bill.

Comment: @PhilipKendall assuming you can get into the bank vault and do that, it becomes a use case of an improvement that an electronic solution could provide.

Comment: And who controls the audit of updates?

Comment: An append only database means you can't update per-se. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/confidential-ledger/overview has built in audit but doesn't allow deletion at all.

Comment: @opticyclic You're missing the point. If I control the whole database, I can just drop the whole thing and recreate it row-by-row with the one row I want changed different.

Comment: @opticyclic:: yes, Philip is right, I wrote this in the very first sentence of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There no such thing like a 100% immutable database  - even if you use a media which cannot physically be altered afterwards, one could copy the whole data store to a second medium and alter some records during this process.

One can only make this process inherently hard, for example by building backups and checksums over certain time periods and store the backups at a physically and organizationally decoupled place. That means, for example, that you instruct two (or more) different organizations for keeping the backups.

Now, if you use, for example, a granularity of one day to "backup-and-freeze" the data, use a storage media like magnetic tape where you can use one physical unit per day, and make sure your "immutable database" can be archived in files-per-day. Then, you instruct your different keeper organizations to shred the tapes which are older than 7 years.

That does not mean you really need to use tapes or physically separated media per day. If you have a some storage media where you can achieve integrity of certain data blocks by some cryptographic measures, though the media physically allows write access, then you can use this, too. But you have to care for creating independent blocks (maybe in the granularity of days, weeks or months), where you can delete a whole block when it gets older than seven years, without affecting other blocks.

If you don't use physically separated media, however, there is always a certain risk that a deletion of an old block accidentally affects a different block of data on the same media. You can mitigate this risk the way I described above: redundancy by different keeper organizations.

Comment: I agree with your sentiment but I'm looking for a software solution and not a hardware one.

Comment: @opticyclic: when you store data over 7 years, you definitely have to think about the hardware first, and you have to think about organizational separation. Any you will not achieve organizational separation when your keeper organizations use the same storage hardware.,

Comment: I agree we need to think about hardware but keeping a physical backup of every single day isn't the most elegant solution to the problem.

Comment: @opticyclic: what deletion granularity does the bank require? Daily, weekly, monthly? I guess after a period of seven years, it does not really matter if they delete the data which is 365 * 7 +1 days old at day 365 * 7, or if they keep it a month longer before it gets deleted.

Comment: @DocBrown I worked for a document management firm which failed to promptly delete financial records at 7 years. The records were seized by tax authorities and used against their owner as evidence of fraud. The owner then won damages against the management firm for their neglect in shredding the documents.